# Expanding macro with value zero as argument

Tags: c++, c, macros

Hi I have following code which should expand to create a register name:

```
#define REG_VAL(base,reg,idx,fld) base##_##reg##_##idx##_##fld
```

This code is working fine if I give idx an other value than 0, but when I give idx as 0,  the macro is not properly expanded. Can someone point out what is the problem here?

For example I have following defines in a header file:

```
#define cpu_control_0_reset   cpu_control_reset_global_reset_0
```

and in my .cpp file I want to use this defined using following macro:

```
REG_VAL(cpu,control,1,reset)
```

So this will correctly result into:

```
cpu_control_1_reset
```

But `REG_VAL(cpu,control,0,reset)` will result into:

```
global_reset_0
```

Comment: Could not reproduce, please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Output with cpp on linux: `cpu_control_1_reset
cpu_control_0_reset` - Maybe it's compiler specific or a bug ?

Comment: Check `#define cpu_control_0_reset` for typos. Maybe it defines     `global_reset_0` instead of `cpu_control_reset_global_reset_0`.

Comment: actually I narrow down the issue is because this is  cpu_control_0_reset   variable is defined in the header file thats why preprocessor trying to optimize this further. While cpu_control_1_reset  is not defined that's why it is correctly generated. When I try to move the header file defining cpu_control_0_reset  ; it gets generated correctly.  So this is something with preprocessor wants to optimize the macro further.  Can you please tell me how to disable this second optimization step?

Comment: @user544414 could you post your narrowed down prombem as MCVE ?

Comment: I got the issue, somehow during compile it was picking older headers which don't have the correct macro definition.  Thanks everyone.